# How do I convert 2-bit string to base64?

Tags: php

I have string of 2 bits (1s and 0s) that is 64 bits/chars long and I would like to base64_encode it in PHP.  How do I convert it to base64?

Here is my string (the right-most char is the 1st bit and the left-most char is the 64th bit):

```
$strBinData = '0110011111011010110101100100000000000000000100000000000010010011' ;
```

By the way I am using PHP v5.3.24.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do but you can convert your binary string to an int value and then use [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

```
$decimalValue = intval($strBinData, 2);
$base64 = base64_encode($decimalValue);
```

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted to do.